# I am having a hard time creating a program that finds tor nodes

Tags: python, html

I am trying to create a web scraping program that goes to a specific website, collects the tor nodes and then compares it to a list that I have. If the IP addresses match then it's a tor node, if not it isn't a tor node then it's false.

I am having a hard time getting the "text" from the inspect element of the website ..[Inspect element of website][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/16zWw.png

Any help is appreciated, I'm stuck right now and don't know how to get the "text" from the first picture to show up on my program. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code to my program so far:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
search = soup.find(id='content')
#137.74.19.201 is practice tor node
items = search.find_all(class_='article box')
```

Comment: Hello. Please insert the source code in your question.

Comment: @Raphael the source code is the second link "Source code of program".

Comment: I know, but we can't copy an image, we need ascii.

Comment: @Raphael I didnt know that. import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
search = soup.find(id='content')
#137.74.19.201 is practice tor node
items = search.find_all(class_='article box')

Comment: @Raphael I updated the post as well to make it easier to read.

Comment: Why bother with BeautifulSoup ?! the guy states clearly that there are some markers in the page ... just take the whole pate as a string, split by those markers an go from there.

Comment: @LohmarASHAR thanks for replying. Im a noob when it comes to programming. How would I do that.

Comment: You can also fetch https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/ (FULL) or https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/?exit (EXIT only) for a list of ips only, one per line - updated every 30 minutes. Ideal for constructing your own tor banlists.

Comment: @Raphael Thats much better I didnt know he had that. But how would I copy the addresses from that webpage and compare them to the list I have.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with BeautifulSoup ?! the guy states clearly that there are some markers in the page ... just take the whole pate as a string, split by those markers an go from there, for example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes')
# assuming that page.content contains the source code of the page

if "<!--__BEGIN_TOR_NODE_LIST__-->" not in page.content:
    print("list not ready")
else:
    list_text = page.content.split("<!--__BEGIN_TOR_NODE_LIST__-->")[1] # take everything after this
    list_text = list_text.split("<!--__END_TOR_NODE_LIST__-->")[1] # take everything before this
    line_list = [line.strip() ]
    for line in list_text.split("<br>"):
        line_ip = line.strip().split("|")[0]
        # how do what you want with it
        if line_ip in my_known_ip_list:
            print("This is good %s" % line_ip)
```

Comment: its saying "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Comment: Replace page.content with page.text

Comment: @dabingsou I did that and it keeps saying list not ready even though it is ready

Comment: That means that the guy blacklisted you for doing too many requests and too often. Read the statement on the page... He says something like no more than a request every half an hour

Answer (score 0):

```py
import urllib.request  # the lib that handles the url stuff

target_url = 'https://www.dan.me.uk/torlist/'

my_ips = ['1.161.11.204', '1.161.11.205']
confirmed_ips = []

for line in urllib.request.urlopen(target_url):
    if line in my_ips:
      print(line.decode())
      confirmed_ips.append(line)

print(confirmed_ips)

# ATTENTION:
# Umm... You can only fetch the data every 30 minutes - sorry.  It's pointless any faster as I only update every 30 minutes anyway.
# If you keep trying to download this list too often, you may get blocked from accessing it completely.
# (this is due to some people trying to download this list every minute!)
```

Since there's this 30min limitation, otherwise you will receive ERROR 403, you can read the lines and save to a file, then compare your list with the downloaded list.

Comment: does this urllib request thing send out a request for every ip in the "my_ips". because if it does thats why it may not work correctly for me. I keep getting that 403 error.

Comment: You need to wait 30 min.